# DiscordJS V12 Add Field Not Returning Correct Value

Tags: discord.js, embed

```
        let chx = db.get(`welchannel_${message.guild.id}`)

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(ee.wrongcolor)
        .setTitle('<:warning:943421375526355024> | **Please Provide A Channel**')
        .addField("__**Current Welcome Channel:**__", `${chx || "None"}`, true)
```

When I provide a channel for my set welcomer channel command it returns 'None' instead of the channel

Comment: Can you give us what returns `chx`?

Comment: it returns the channel ID

Comment: Can you log it to be sure?

Comment: i did log it and it returns the channel id

Comment: nvm it does log the channel id i just cant figure out how to add <# > to the start and end

Answer (score -1):

```
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(ee.wrongcolor)
    .setTitle('<:warning:943421375526355024> | **Please Provide A Channel**')
    .addField("__**Current Welcome Channel:**__", `None`, true)

    let embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(ee.wrongcolor)
    .setTitle('<:warning:943421375526355024> | **Please Provide A Channel**')
    .addField("__**Current Welcome Channel:**__", `<#${chx}>`, true)

    if (chx === null) {
        if(!channel) {
            return message.channel.send(embed)
        }
    } else {
        if(!channel) {
            return message.channel.send(embed2)
        }
    }
```

works fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).